# ISipRegistrationListener.OnRegistrationDone( ) giving too high values for expiration time

Tags: android, xamarin.android, sip

I'm successfully registering a SipProfile with 1 hour expiration.  I see the REGISTER message in Wireshark on the SIP server machine, re-sent with authorization.
Brekeke replies immediately with a STATUS: 200 OK, passing back 'Expires:3600'.

[image: Wireshark capture of SIP registration]

Both [Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Net.Sip.ISipRegistrationListener.OnRegistrationDone/p/System.String/System.Int64/) and [Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipRegistrationListener#onRegistrationDone(java.lang.String,%20long)) docs tell me that `lExpire` should be *duration in seconds before the registration expires*, so it represents an interval.  I want to expose received values, so multiply by `TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond` (to convert to TimeSpan), 3600 would result in `0.01:00:00`:

```
void    ISipRegistrationListener.OnRegistrationDone( string lclPrfUri, long lExpire )
{
    long    l=  DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    double  d=  (double)l / lExpire;
    string  s=  string.Format( "RegSucced( '{0}', {1} ), {2}, {3}", lclPrfUri, lExpire,
                    new TimeSpan( lExpire * TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond )
                        .ToString( "d\\.hh\\:mm\\:ss" ), d );
    ..
}
```

But i'm getting `lExpire` values in the range of 1.5 trillions (1'541'195'345'242)!

As i saw it *constantly* growing with time, i thought it might be related to Ticks, so i exposed both and gathered the following statistics (H == T + 1 hour -- expected expiration):

```
    #  DT.Now.Ticks (T)     lExpire (E)     T/E ratio   T+36000000000 (H)   H/E ratio
    1  636767624266839520   1541183611836   413167.918  636767660266839520  413167.941
    2  636767669188704010   1541188122398   413166.738  636767705188704010  413166.761
    3  636767670260843180   1541188229643   413166.710  636767706260843180  413166.733
    4  636767670974718350   1541188301027   413166.691  636767706974718350  413166.715
    5  636767693193745790   1541190522922   413166.110  636767729193745790  413166.133
```

And the ratios look surprisingly consistent, though the *magic* of 413166 escapes me..  And from that `lExpire` looks more like *a reference to a point in time, than an interval*, no?

*But according to docs i should get 3600 without any scaling factors, right?* **What is going on??!**

[image: Android screenshot]

**UPDATE (2019-Jan-25)**

Finally got closer to an answer.  Digging through Android source files (e.g. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/431bb2269532f2514861b908d5fafda8fa64da79/voip/java/com/android/server/sip/SipService.java) i found the following fragment:

```
@Override
public void onRegistrationDone(ISipSession session, int duration) {
    if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "onRegistrationDone(): " + session); 
    synchronized (SipService.this) { 
        if (notCurrentSession(session)) return; 

        mProxy.onRegistrationDone(session, duration); 

        if (duration > 0) { 
            mSession.clearReRegisterRequired(); 
            mExpiryTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + (duration * 1000);
    ..
```

`SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` [returns milliseconds since boot](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock), including time spent in sleep.
Time in UNIX/Linux/Java is kept [as number of seconds since epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z).

Wikipedia's page shows Current Unix time as 1548450313 (2019-01-25T21:05:13+00:00), which is only a 1000 times (*s*-to-*ms* multiplier!) different in range from `lExpire` values i observe.  The formula for `mExpiryTime` in the last line kinda gives hope.. "Eureka!"?

Let's check if they conform to "*# of ms since epoch*" theory:

```
DateTime    dtEpoch =   new DateTime( 1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc );

void    ISipRegistrationListener.OnRegistrationDone( string lclPrfUri, long lExpire )
{
    DateTime    dt =    dtEpoch.AddMilliseconds( lExpire ).ToLocalTime( );
    string  s=  string.Format( "RegSucced( '{0}', {1}, {2} )", lclPrfUri, lExpire,
                                    dt.ToString( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff" ) );
    ..
}
```

Yesterday's screenshots - with that addition (magenta arrows mark exposed values):
[image: Android screenshots]

As you can see, the difference between `lExpire` converted into time and `DateTime.Now` (captured in the log) is negligible - in ms range!

I actually like the idea of being given an *expiration **moment*** instead of *duration* (which need to be added to an *undefined* starting point).  Was about to answer my question..

**But still, there are follow-up unresolved mysteries**:

1. Why documentation says the argument is *duration in seconds*?
   Xamarin may be just copying Android docs, but **the source is way wrong**!
   Is this really how lame Android devs are?  Reckon that should be rethorical ((..
   Does anybody care that requested expiration period may be trumped [*down*] by PBX /SIP server, and thus they have to re-register *more often*?
2. All calls to `.onRegistrationDone(session, duration)` in the source files specify `duration`, not `mExpiryTime`.
   There are constant definitions (EXPIRY_TIME = 3600, SHORT_EXPIRY_TIME = 10, MIN_EXPIRY_TIME = 60) and comparisons of `duration` to these..
   Range of values is drastically different between the two (3600 vs 15 trillion).
   How/where does mExpiryTime (*expiration moment*) make it into the argument of my method?
3. *ms since boot* and *s (or ms) since epoch* are still very different, what makes *that* adjustment?
4. and finally, asking a 1 hr expiration and receiving it in the OK reply from SIP server, i expect that to be reflected here too, so **`lExpire` should be 1 hr in the future, not *now***!!

Any ideas?

Comment: Not quite get the meaning of double  d=  (double)l / lExpire; As l (long    l=  DateTime.Now.Ticks;) means the number of ticks that have elapsed since the beginning of the twenty-first century

Comment: For more info, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: The thought was, maybe observed value is tied to Ticks?

Comment: Why do you use `DateTime.Now.Ticks` to divided by lExpire?

Comment: Because the values of `lExpire` that i observe keep growing with time. So i thought maybe they are scaled from Ticks. => i tried to get stats on their ratio.  While not exact that ratio is close to 413166±5, which is not magic in any way to me.  I'll add stats to the question.